# Random data Structure in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I was wondering if someone can help

I need to make an lmer model based on the following data structure:

3 blocks
2 sections per block (given 2 different climates)
3 plots per section (given 3 different amounts of fertilizer)
2 subplots per plot (with 2 different varieties)

[image: data frame]

The response variable is rate. I don't understand the difference between "normal variable" and "mixed variable. Can someone give the missing code:

```
fit.cucumber.1 <- lmer(rate ~ ........., data = cucumber)
```

The following as a part of the cucumber data frame

Best regards,
Gunnar

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any random effects?  If all of these are fixed effects, then you just enter the terms "as is".  Any random effect would be denoted `(1 | myvar)`.

So your model with all fixed effects would be:
`fit.cucumber.1 <- lmer(rate ~ block + section + plot, data = cucumber)`

I am not sure this would run though without specifying one or more random effects (i.e., that's the mixed component)